Why isn't the CLK input manipulated directly in flip flops?
In Ben Eater's video he uses a circuit below to create a D-Flip-Flop with a LOAD pin. 
From my understanding, the circuit makes it so that the flip flop only loads in D1 or input when LOAD is high, otherwise it does nothing. However, I'm confused why the CLK input couldn't be manipulated directly like in top circuit below.
From my testing, they appear the same.

So why isn't the CLK input manipulated directly?

In your design if LOAD goes from low to high while CLK is high, it will create a rising edge at the flip-flop and transfer the input to the output, which is not desired behavior. It may also create a timing violation (runt clock pulse) at the flip-flop.

One problem with combinational logic is that the input signals "propagate" through the various gates at finite speed, as they traverse the system. That means that even if you set the inputs all at the same instant in time, the results of those inputs will arrive at different points in the system at different times, having been "delayed" by each gate traversed.
For instance, in your top diagram, the "input" signal will arrive at the flip-flop (its D-input) before the result of ANDing signals "load" and "clk", because it takes a few nanoseconds for the AND gate to do its thing. Eventually the signals will all settle at their expected values, but it won't ever be instantaneous.
In your second circuit, the "load" input has to "traverse" an inverter, and AND gate and another OR gate, before the result finally arrives at D. The "input" signal, by contrast only has to propagate through two gates, the AND and the OR. If you "clocked" the D-flipflop (with "clk") before enough time has elapsed, the signal being read at D will not be correct.
That means you have to be really careful when you clock the D-flipflop, or, in other words, when you actually instruct the D-flipflop to "read" its D input. It's possible that the various sources of data will all have to traverse different numbers of gates, and will all be subject to different "propagation delays", and you'll need to wait a few nanoseconds for everything to settle, before you can trust the final value of D. Only then should you trigger the flip-flop with a clock edge, and "latch" the value of D into Q.
Of course, that may not be a problem in your own particular application, and so you may clock the flip-flop however you like, directly or indirectly, but in so-called "synchronous" systems, flip-flops are generally clocked after some delay, enough time for the D input to have settled at the expected value.
Real-life flip-flops also have a "setup time", which is the minimum time you must wait between presenting a voltage at the D (or J, K, R, S) input, and clocking the flip-flop, to guarantee that D (or J, K, R, S) are interpreted correctly. That's another reason why you'd typically use a clocking signal which is independent of the system producing the values to be latched, or otherwise operated upon.
In 6502 systems (which Ben Eater covers extensively), there are two clock signal sources, \$\phi_1\$ and \$\phi_2\$. These are used by various peripherals (and the 6502 itself) to signal when it's safe to "read" or "write" data to/from the address and data bus lines. They are inverted with respect to each other, but also delayed slightly, to allow for the time it takes the address and data bus lines to "settle". External devices can choose which "edges" of \$\phi_1\$ and \$\phi_2\$ to use as their "clock", safe in the knowledge that the information they are "reading" has had time to settle, and is correct, or that they have enough time to present data onto those lines prior to the CPU accessing them.
